# Listen DNS requests with Java in continuous and execute cmd command

Tags: java, windows, cmd, dns, sniffer

Ok let's be precise. For many days I've been asking myself a question : **Could it be possible to listen DNS request on a computer** ( in my case a windows machine ) **and ask to the program to execute a shell command if a special DNS is detected ?**

I've been playing with this command :

ipconfig /displaydns | find "my.dns.com"

And as expected I'm able to find "my.dns.com" in my DNS cache.

**BUT**  I'm not able to ask to the cmd :

> Hey, listen for all the requests in continuous and when you detect
>   "my.dns.com" please execute "music.exe".

So I imagined a program ( in Java ) doing it for me. Why java ? Because i'ts the only programming language that I'm able to use, I started with it so it's easier for me to understand it. But if what I'm looking for is not possible in Java, let me know it !

**BUT** ( again ) I don't know how to manage with DNS requests and neither ask for a java program to run in continuous. For the moment here is everything I could add to my program :

```
if ("my.dns.com" is detected) {
try {
String command = "cmd /c start music.exe";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

And maybe for running in continuous :

```
boolean running = true;
while(running)
{
  //main loop...
}
```

I know, that is very few but I don't even know where to look to answer my question.

Please, if you'r able to understand me ( Yes you behind your screen while eating Doritos ) could you at least help me to find my way ?

Precise if you want me to edit it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this (untested) clip of PowerShell will get you going. I do not know that it is a good idea to clear the DNS cache, but that is up to you. If you do not, it will still be in there.

```
while ($true) {
    $a = Get-DnsClientCache | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }
    if ($a -contains 'the.dns.com') {
        Start-Process C:\path\to\music.exe -Wait
        Clear-DnsClientCache
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I definitely tried this script, and sorry to say it but, it doesn't work :( The script executes well but nothing happened when I travel to the specific DNS. At least, thanks for your help :) @lit

Comment: Please try running `Get-DnsClientCache | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }` alone at a PowerShell prompt. Is the domain you are looking for in the output? Also, you must leave this script running while you browse to the domain in question.

Comment: So I tried, and indeed it shows me few DNS, but not the one I want :(. But it works when I put a DNS present in the list. By the way, thanks @lit ;)

Comment: I do not know why "your" DNS did not appear in the cache. Was there something similar to it?

Comment: Hey, I want to inform you of your piece of code : That's perfect :) thanks a lot @lit. But I have just another question : How I can add another DNS in addition of this one ? Because when I try with `-Or 'another.dns.com'` it makes a fork-bomb like, openning a lot of tabs.

Comment: Please ask another question on SO.